# QGIS 2.14.3 constantly crashing when digitizing

Tags: qgis, select-by-location

I'm using QGIS 2.14.3 Essen on Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela. I'm digitizing either into .OGR vector file or a Spatialite database. Same happens with both.

I can be digitizing a string, I complete it with right mouse button, I then add in the attributes (automatically created unique id) and save. I then save the element. So, typically I'll then select another string nearby - with 'Select Feature by Area or Single Click' and then I crash straight out. If I haven't saved the line string I've lost it of course.

The message I get from the terminal is:

> "ERROR 4: Permission denied qgis.bin: geos_ts_c.cpp:3657: int
>   GEOSCoordSeq_setOrdinate_r(GEOSContextHandle_t,
>   geos::geom::CoordinateSequence*, unsigned int, unsigned int, double):
>   Assertion `0 != cs' failed."

Comment: What CRS is the layer defined as?

Comment: I suggest to update to QGIS 2.14.11 LTR. Maybe the bug has already been fixed.

Comment: The CRS is defined as WGS 84, authority ID: EPSG 4326 - this is the project CRS. I have update to 2.14.12 LTR from http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr trusty main
The problem is still occurring but less. I'm not sure that 2.18.4 will work with Trusty/Rafaella

Comment: The LTR Version is 2.14.12 now